# How to get a substring between two characters where order of characters matter?

Tags: unix, substring

I have an Unix shell script and I want to get the substring between _ and -, but NOT - and _.

Example:

```
cs-ui-21140322175352_8ddjdb1b4cc4a87d17034dd3704q5a0ea60d6d87-2.x86_64
```

I want to extract:

```
8ddjdb1b4cc4a87d17034dd3704q5a0ea60d6d87
```

And store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more undersores and other things than your sample input.
For your sample input you can do something like

```
newvar=$(echo "${inputstr}" | sed -e 's/[^_]*_//' -e 's/-.*//')
# or
newvar=$(echo "${inputstr}" | sed -e 's/.*_\(.*\)-.*/\1/')
# or
newvar=$(echo "${inputstr}" | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "-" -f1)
```

Comment: I got 64 on the first one. The second one worked fine. The last one gave me an error: cut: [-cf] list: illegal list value
cut: [-cf] list: values may not include zero

Comment: Sorry, corrected. First one was a greedy `.*`, just need to tell to eat all except _. The cut delimiter is option d, not c.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputstr=cs-ui-21140322175352_8ddjdb1b4cc4a87d17034dd3704q5a0ea60d6d87-2.x86_64

newvar=`echo $inputstr | sed  's,.*_\(.*\)-.*,\1,'`
```

Comment: This looks like my second solution. Please note that `$(cmd)` is safer and easier than backtics.